# models.CASCADE нужна помощь! Очистил одну таблицу, и вместе с ней очистилась другая. Django 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-orm, django-model

Все банально просто: Есть модель с данными отделений, и есть модель заказов где

```
warehouse = models.ForeignKey(Warehouse, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name='Отделение НП', blank=True, null=True)
```

Оказалось, что при обновлении модели Warehouse(стороннее приложение) сначала вся таблица очищается, и соответвенно модель Order полностью очистилась.
Да, это моя ошибка было указывать CASCADE а не Do_NOTHING.
Есть ли какие то варианты откатить изменения в таблице order? И вообще, возможно ли в Django из коробки защита вот от таких ошибок?

**Помогите...!!!**

Comment: Какую базу используете?

Comment: Sqlite3. Проблема уже решена - банальным бэкапом при массовом удалении значений. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема уже решена - банальным бэкапом при массовом удалении значений. Спасибо!